# Podio API Item last activity date

Tags: podio

I'm trying to get the last activity date and time on an item.

Using `/item/app/{app_id}/filter/` I am able to sort in order of activity, but the payload of each item returned does not contain a last activity date.

Trying to get the complete item with `/item/{item_id}` there is no last activity date either.

The only date on each item is `last_event_on` which does not cater for events like comments. last_event_on only records edits to the item itself.

Now I could just grab the last comment and see it's date, but this could be wrong as any comment may have been edited recently to give as a more recent activity date.

How can Podio's API filter and sort by a date that's so hard to come by?

Any way to get the last activity date as part of the payload?